# How can I add bubbles to a liquid?

Tags: rendering

I have been using blender for just a couple of years off and on and wanted some suggestions on this render, things like:
[image: Main render]

How to add bubbles over the wine?

Comment: Well i changed it now

Comment: You need to use particle system for creating bubbles. Give them surface material & you got your bubbles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a particle with sphere object wherever you want in that liquid.
Set the liquid material to objects of that particle.
Flip normals of the sphere objects so that the inside of them will look like air.
These are my bubbles:
[image]