# Sides and volume of object not rendered through glass

Tags: light

I have been trying to render a simple glass of milk. Yet parts of the milk is not rendering.
[image]
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This partially looks like a Z-Fighting problem.

Try scaling up your Milk Mesh to where its perimeter edges are in the middle of the glass' inner and outer walls and try again.

To do this:

1. Select your Milk Mesh.
2. <kbd>S</kbd>.
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>
4. Move your mouse until it is lined up >> <kbd>LMB</kbd>.

---

Also, if this is still not working altogether after that:

---

1. Select your Milk Mesh.
2. Go into edit mode (<kbd>TAB</kbd> to toggle).
3. <kbd>A</kbd> to select all.
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.
5. 2. Go back into Object mode (<kbd>TAB</kbd> to toggle).

Now try rendering again. If it is still not working then hopefully we can get you to post your .blend file

---

After taking a look at your blend file, here is what I did to get the following results:

[image: Glass Of Milk Results - 001]

[image]
1. I applied your Boolean Modifier.

[image]
[image]
2. I did the scaling step listed above.

[image]
3. I modified your glass material to that shown in the result image.

[image]
4. I added a Sun Lamp with a Strength of 5.0 (Using Nodes).

Comment: Thank you for your support but both of your solutions are not working. I will post my .blend file on dropbox: [Glass of Milk.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3z4r2s3ds4uoa1/Glass%20of%20Milk.blend?dl=1)

Comment: @Alex12321 - I've appended my answer for your review.

Comment: I am new to this, what does that mean?

Comment: @Alex12321 Dont thank for answers, upvote instead if they helped you, or mark them as accepted if they solved your problemm

Comment: It just means that I've added extra information to my answer, so that you can look at it, try it, and either mark it answered or express items that are still not working for you.